# In Perl, how can I append a regex match with output from an external command in a substation?

Tags: regex, perl

Let's say I have a list of IPs that looks like this:

10.2.3.4
10.5.3.2
10.5.3.1
...

I know about the 'e' option in regex, which does an eval against the replacement string.  I just wanted to do a straight up replacement, I could do this:

```
s/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/`{$1}dig -x $1 +short`/ge;
```

But, what I really want to do is append the host name to regex match like this:

10.2.3.4    website.example.com
10.5.3.2    dc01.example.com
10.5.3.1    dc02.example.com
...

Comment: Rather than relying on backticks, I would recommend finding a suitable module on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/).

Comment: `s/substation/substitution/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works for me:

```
s/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/"$1 ". `dig -x $1 +short`/ge;
```

Comment: @anonymous downvoter: I accept the down vote, but I would like to understand the reasoning behind it. I tested the regex and it produces the output the OP is looking for... what is the problem with this?

Answer (score 4):

If you all you need to do is append, you don't need a regex at all.  Just do:

```
chomp($_ .= '  ' . qx(dig -x $_ +short)) for @list;
```

I'm not sure what the `{$1}` is for in your example, though.

Comment: Oops, the `{$1}` was from me trying to figure out a way to do this.  I'll remove it from the question.

But, I simplified my example text.  I actually have more in the string that just the IP so I do need the regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
s/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/$1.`{$1}dig -x $1 +short`/ge;
```